# CodeIgniter Skeleton, submenus lost path to css and js

Tags: codeigniter

I decided to use CodeIgniter-Skeleton-master (author Anvoz) for build my web site.
I added new menus and sub menus on this example.
With setup new menus I haven't problem, because I copy example of Todo, make Todo1 and it works without any problem.
But, on all added submenus I entered under Todo1 displayed web page cannot proper access to css and js files and navbar is displayed without css and js.
Problem was caused what site url() grab controller name todo1 and css and js is in the wrong path !

**Example:**

`todo1 ->path : http://localhost/ci3a/ ->this` work ok instead all used css and js path is added onto this and have acess to their files
`todo1/aboutus ->path : http://localhost/ci3a/todo1 ->this` controller name-todo1 cause wrong path and css and js files cannot be used!

Organisation of files :
application
assets, contain css, images and js subfolders
system

In application/config/
assets.php I have:

```
$config['assets_url'] = 'assets/';
```

autoload.php I have:

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

config.php I have:

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

routes.php I have:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "skeleton";
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

In application/skeleton/ i have
controllers and views folders

In controllers folder I have main controller skeleton.php

In application/views/header.php I have navbar menu structure.
Here I put the copy of todo menu->todo1 with 2 submenus, who work but dont display css and js

```
        <li class="dropdown">

            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">

                Todo1 <b class="caret"></b>

            </a>

            <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('todo1'); ?>">Todo1</a></li>

                <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('todo1/aboutus'); ?>">About us</a></li>


                <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('todo1/whereweare'); ?>">Where we are</a></li>

            </ul>

        </li>
```

I added similar functions as index (in todo1.php controller) for this new submenuus)

```
public function aboutus()

{

   $this->load->library('template');


   $this->template->set_layout('pagelet');

   $this->template->set_title('Todo example');


   $this->template->load_view('todo1/aboutus');

}
```

I dont know how to eliminate this controller name who make css, image and js unaccesible.
I tried to make new folder todo1 under root and copy access subfolder into it but the problem stayed.
In web browser, i cought errors:

```
GET http://localhost/ci3a/todo1/aboutus [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 63ms]
GET http://localhost/ci3a/todo1/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css [HTTP/1.1 404
```

Not Found 141ms]
and x similar errors
Can you someone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

to load your css and js

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

so that your folder structurer would be like this

```
1. application
2. assets
    - css
        1. bootstrap.css
    - js
        1. bootstrap.js
    - images
        1. slider.jpg
        2. logo.jpg
3. system
4. .htacess
5. index.php
```

in controller just load your particular view only

```
public function aboutus()
{

   $this->template->set_title('Todo example');
   $this->template->load_view('todo1/header');
   $this->template->load_view('todo1/aboutus');//this should contain only about us details
   $this->template->load_view('todo1/fotter');
}
```

so in `header.php` file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>my site ----</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
```

in so in `fotter.php` file

```
<div class="foot">
    <div class="social">
        <div class="news_letter">
            <p>Sign Up For Newsletter</p>
            <div class="new_div">
                <form action="#" class="form_news" method="post">
                    <input type="email" class="news_input" placeholder="E-Mail" name="email" required>
                    <input type="submit" class="news_button" value="Subscribe" name="news_but" >
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="follow">
            <p>Follow Me</p>
            <ul class="soc">
                <li><a class="soc-facebook" href="#" target="_blank"></a></li>
                <li><a class="soc-twitter" href="#"></a></li>
                <li><a class="soc-linkedin soc-icon-last" href="#"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="copyright navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="copy_in">
            <div class="foot_nav navbar-text">
                <ul>
                    <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>"><li class="list_border">Home</li></a>
                    <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/aboutUs"><li class="list_border">About Us</li></a>
                    <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/product"><li class="list_border">Products</li></a>
                    <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/corsair"><li class="list_border">Corsair</li></a>
                    <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/contact"><li>Contact Us</li></a>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="foot_copy_text">
                <p class="navbar-text">
                    © 2015 - comany name. Solution By : <a href="#" target="_blank">My office name</a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

in between (ex:about us page)

```
<div class="container">

    <h1>Im About us</h1>
 <!-- rest of code here -->
</div>
```

ex: contact

```
<div class="container">

    <h1>Im contact</h1>
    <!-- rest of code here -->
</div>
```

Comment: Problem is in file application/config/assets.php
Replace line:
$config['assets_url'] = 'assets/';
with:
$config['assets_url'] = '/assets/';

Also replace this line in application/helpers/My_url_helper.php :
        return $assets_url . trim($uri, '/');
with:
        return base_url( $assets_url . trim($uri, '/') );

Comment: Yes, with this approvements in assets.php and My_url_helper.php! One friend helped me aboit this answer, here in my town!

Comment: @Kresimir_CRO if my answer help full or you think it will help full for other users please accept it